# gnuplot postscript+eps linewidth

Tags: gnuplot, postscript, eps

How to adjust linewidth in the postscript+eps terminal? I need to get linewidth=1.0 (border or axis), linewidth=1.8 (data-file1), linewidth=1.0 (data-file2)

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced font 'Times-Roman,14' lw 1.5
    set output 'figure.eps'
...

plot 'P-Density.txt' u 1:(0.415+$2) axes x1y2 title '(1,0,0)' w line lt 1 lc 9 lw 1.8, 'P-Density.txt' u 1:(0.472+$3) axes x1y2 title '(1,1,0)' w line lt 1 lc 1 lw 1.8, 'P-Density.txt' u 1:(0.658+$4) axes x1y2 title '(1,2,0)' w line lt 1 lc 3 lw 1.8, 'Potential.txt' u 1:2 title '' w line ls -1 lw 1.2, 'enerji2_7_1.txt' u 1:2 title '' w line lt 2 lc 9 lw 1.0, 'enerji2_7_2.txt' u 1:2 title '' w line lt 2 lc 1 lw 1.0, 'enerji2_7_3.txt' u 1:2 title '' w line lt 2 lc 3 lw 1.0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you ask a question, please also provide some description of any error you get. As it is now, we need to guess what is wrong, because your code sample should already give you different linewidths for the different elements of your plot.

Answer (score 0):

In the "postscript" terminal, the thickness of the tick marks will follow the line width set by the `set border` command, but the border is designed to be twice as thick.
Then, if you want the border line to be 1.0 thickness, you can set it as follows.

```
set border lw 0.5
```

Instead, the tick marks thickness will be set to 0.5.

If you want the line width of the border and tick marks to match, you need to change the contents of the file "prologue.ps", which is embedded in the header of the output postscript file. gnuplot provides a mechanism to replace this header with your own customized "prologue.ps" file. See `help set psdir` for details.

You can try it by copying the 'prologue.ps' file that comes with gnuplot to the current directory, and changing the line,

```
/LTB {BL [] LCb DL} def
```

to the following.

```
/LTB {PL [] LCb DL} def
```

Then, change your script as,

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced font 'Times-Roman,14' 
set psdir '.'
set output 'figure.eps'

set border lw 1.0

... your plot command ...
```